# Did not receive additional privileges per "Join Meta today and earn extra privileges like posting, commenting and voting."

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I did not receive additional privileges per "*Join Meta today and earn extra privileges like posting, commenting and voting.*" This message shows up if you (for example) try to comment without an account.

I believe this may be because I used my previously existing SO login, so FYI you appear to be unintentionally penalizing new Meta users for having a previous SO login.

.. ***Moderator*** so to accomplish *".. earn extra privileges like posting, commenting and voting."* as promised - I believe you should kindly credit this StackId account at least 5 reputation please.

Comment: Where did you see this promise exactly? I've never seen any special privs offered to join Meta.SE

Comment: Yes you did... by having an account here, you're able to post, and you'll be able to vote and comment when you reach the required level of reputation - hence _earn_ extra privileges.

Comment: I can see how that statement might be ambiguous.  Read it as "Join Meta today and gain the opportunity to earn extra privileges like posting, commenting and voting."

Comment: This "earn" isn't meant to be a promise but an instruction.

Comment: Ah, so OP didn't misread, you do get reputation as promised, but you have to ask for it first!

Comment: @opa I think the OP _did_ misread. But it's not his fault. There are a few hidden if's in this sentence (which you only know if you have some experience with SE sites): _If you join ... and if you contribute (Qs & As) ... and if your contributions are valued (upvoted) by others then you earn ..._ So, literally "ask for" isn't the proper wording.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I was making a joke... they got the reputation they wanted via asking this question and people up-voting it.

Comment: @opa I see. Yes, I didn't get this right. But..."they"? He's just one. (Or is this a [humorous?] reference to ongoing discussions about recent decisions? Or even anticipatory obedience? :)